# multiple field validation using livewire ? name.0.required is working but name.*.required is not working. Please provide me solution

Tags: validation, laravel-livewire

I want to validate all field. But It is validating only first field. Append field is not validating

[image: This is link for picture showing my error on multi field validation]

multiple fields validation using livewire? name.0.required is working but name.*.required is not working.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $inputs = [];
    public $i = 1;
 
    public function add($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->inputs ,$i);
    }
 
    public function remove($i)
    {
        unset($this->inputs[$i]);
    }
 
    public function store()
    {
        $validatedDate = $this->validate([
                'name.0' => 'required',
                'name.*' => 'required',
            ],
            [
                'name.0.required' => 'name field is required',
                'name.*.required' => 'name field is required',
            ]
        );

        session()->flash('message', 'Name Has Been Created Successfully.');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}


<div>
    <form class="offset-md-3">
        @if (session()->has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('message') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="add-input">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="name.0">
                        @error('name.0') <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn text-white btn-info btn-sm" wire:click.prevent="add({{$i}})">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
        <div class=" add-input">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="name.{{ $value }}">
                        @error('name.'.$value) <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" wire:click.prevent="remove({{$key}})">remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="store()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my full code use to create multi field using livewire. I am not able to validate appended field so I need help to solve this problem. This validate first field name.0 other append field name.* does not validate.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $key instead $value.

Like this:

```php
wire:model="name.{{ $key }}"
```